# Intellij Ultimate 2020.2 uses huge amount of memory and lags

Tags: html, intellij-idea, javafx

Recently, I have issues with my Intellij Ultimate IDE. It has been going out of memory quite often and I would need to restart the project. Initially, I thought that it might have been some memory leaks due to JavaFX. However, even with HTML (without JS) it still lags. I need to create a GUI for my school project.
Any idea what's wrong? Is it my IDE or my code?

P.S. I have allocated around 2GB ram for Intellij by default.

Comment: If you are paying for Intellij Ultimate, why not reach out to customer support? This does not seem to be `JavaFX` or `HTML` specific so those tags may not be relevant. I added the `Intellij-Idea` tag.

Comment: Do you have the codota or CSV plugins for intellij?  If so, try disabling them.